# Beginner Shading Problem

Tags: shaders

I am new to Blender and I am having a hard time fixing some shading issues. I could really use your knowledge and experience!

**What I am Trying to Make:** I'm trying to make a car tyre using Blender Guru's tutorial, available at https://youtu.be/WhmRn-tYtxE.

**The Problem:** When I array my mesh around a curve (the curve has resolution set to 200), I get subtle shading issues wherever the mesh meets (highlighted in red in the image).
I have enabled merge and removed duplicate vertices, but I can't seem to get rid of the issue. The .blend file is available here: [tyre_issue_blend_file.](https://pasteall.org/blend/3a6d0e5ba55f42e18c7123c8b1829d6e)

[image]

I would really appreciate any help with this issue. I really want to understand why this is happening, and how I can fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: hello, maybe you have flipped normals and you need to recalculate the normals? Or you have an inner face? maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for replying! I have recalculated the normals, and I don't think I have an inner face. I have enabled auto smooth and it seems to have helped, but now I have another issue. When I array my mesh around a curve (with resolution set to 200), I get subtle seams wherever the mesh meets. I have enabled merge and removed duplicate vertices, but I can't seem to get rid of the issue. Do you have any ideas? Thanks again. I have uploaded my .blend file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/3a6d0e5ba55f42e18c7123c8b1829d6e

Comment: could you please edit your original question and show the new issue with some screenshots? I can't see the seam you're talking about

Comment: Hi, I have edited my original question to address the new issue, and added a screen shot. The issue is hard to see, but it is there. It is visible with glossy matcap. If you move around with shift and middle mouse button, if looks like the verts aren't aligned correctly, but they are as far as I can see. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes as Ribbit says I'm not sure either there's any problem, Edge Split is a bit unconventional but it's not the problem here

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with the shading of your mesh, it's just the reflection of the light from that particular white ceramic matcap Look in the answers section  for pictures

Comment: Thank you @moonboots, you've been very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem with the shading of your mesh, it's just the reflection of the light from that particular **white ceramic matcap** as the issue isn`t shown in any other matcaps. To be honest **I am not completely sure.**

**Your mesh previewed with the white ceramic matcap**

[image]

**Your mesh previewed with the red metal matcap**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you for taking the time to reply with images and a gif! This makes it clearer for me, thank you.

Comment: Your welcome ;) really happy to help

Answer (score 3):

When you switch to smooth shading, for geometry like yours, you should also enable AutoSmooth by going to the Properties Panel; selecting Object Data Properties; (the one with the triangle icon,) opening the Normals tab and enabling AutoSmooth:

[image: Autosmooth option]

Here is geometry that is similar to yours, with smooth shading enabled.

Without autosmooth set:

[image: no autosmooth]

With autosmooth set

[image: with autosmooth]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! I have enabled Auto Smooth (and set the angle to 35 degrees). It seems to have done the trick. However, I am now encountering another issue. When I array my mesh around a curve, I get subtle seams where the mesh meets. I have enabled merge and removed duplicate vertices, but I can't seem to get rid of the issue. Do you have any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: I downloaded your file and the apparent issues all seem to be due to lighting.  Your mesh looks fine, and when I switch to a matte matcap they don't show up.